# Send the dropdownlist value to the controllers action when link is pressed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc 3 and I want to trigger the GridView action and pass the dropdownlist selected value in the action parameter.

```
@Html.ActionLink("View", "GridAction", new { action = $("#DropDownList1").val() });
```

Comment: You should accept an answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the link's `href` attribute in the dropdown's client-side `change` event.

For example:

```
$('#DropDownList1').change(function() {
    $('a#something').attr('href', '/View/GridAction/' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: do u have an example of that? Don't I have to submit the form in order to send the values to the actions?

Comment: That did  not work! Don't I have to use querystring or something. Your example comes like View/GridAction/exportgrid

Comment: Obviously, you need to modify the URL.

Comment: actually that is the url I am using. I have a GridAction(string action) do I need to change that?